# What code solution to these ranges in java

Tags: java, android

Hello I would like to make a method that takes a given weight and windspeed and picks the right kite. The tricky part is the ranges. Any idea. I was thinking either if-else or a switch ?
[Picture of table I wanna code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F3gy.jpg)

Ive tried:

```
 if((5<wind && wind<10) && (40 < weight && weight< 50)){
            txt_kite.setText( "10-11 m^2");
        }
        else if((5<wind && wind<10) && (50 < weight && weight< 60)){
            txt_kite.setText( "11-12 m^2");
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your code and where you have problems with so we can help?

Comment: @n247s i was thinking of doing this for all, but that's a lot of kode  if((5<wind && wind<10) && (40 < weight && weight< 50)){
            txt_kite.setText( "Blue kite ");
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the ifs to avoid having to check the wind every time. Also keep in mind that in your example code it doesn't handle it when someone is exactly weight 50 so you need to include it in either case. I would also just let the function just return the String and use that function in the setText. So you get

```
public static String getKite(int wind, int weight) {
    if (5 < wind && wind <= 10) {
        if (40 < weight && weight <= 50) return "10-11 m^2";
        if (50 < weight && weight <= 60) return "11-12 m^2";
        //the rest of the weights
    } else if (7 < wind && wind <= 12) {
        if (40 < weight && weight <= 50) return "8-9 m^2";
        //all with this wind
    }
    // add the other winds here

    return "no kite possible";
}
```

and do

```
txt_kite.setText(getKite(wind, weight));
```

there where you want it.
Also keep in mind that with this code at wind 8 for example it would pick the 5-10 category and not the 7-12. I don't know which one should be prioritized since the table has these overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you write all conditions with ifs you will get a very convoluted and unreadable code.

You could instead use a strategy pattern and kite objects that are chosen by matching the correct strategy:

```
public class Main {

    // even better would be to use a factory for holding the strategies
    private static Set<KiteSelectionStrategy> strategies = null; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int wind = 6;
        int weight = 45;
        String kite = getKiteValue(wind, weight);
        System.out.println(kite);
    }

    private static String getKiteValue(int wind, int weight) {
        initStrategies();
        KiteSelectionStrategy selectedStrategy = strategies.stream()
                .filter(strategy -> strategy.isMatch(wind, weight))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
        if (selectedStrategy == null)
            return "No kite found.";
        return selectedStrategy.getKite().value();
    }

    private static void initStrategies() {
        if (strategies == null) {
            // I'm using org.reflections here
            strategies = new Reflections().getSubTypesOf(KiteSelectionStrategy.class).stream()
                    .map(strategy -> getInstance(strategy))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }

    private static KiteSelectionStrategy getInstance(Class<? extends KiteSelectionStrategy> strategy) throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            return strategy.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // this will crash your program so you can handle gracefully instead
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How your strategy will look:

```
public abstract class KiteSelectionStrategy {

    private final int minWind;
    private final int maxWind;
    private final int minWeight;
    private final int maxWeight;

    protected KiteSelectionStrategy(int minWind, int maxWind, int minWeight, int maxWeight) {
        this.minWind = minWind;
        this.maxWind = maxWind;
        this.minWeight = minWeight;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
    }

    public boolean isMatch(int wind, int weight) {
        return minWind < wind && wind <= maxWind && minWeight < weight && weight <= maxWeight;
    }

    abstract Kite getKite();
}

public class Wind1Weight1KiteSelectionStrategy extends KiteSelectionStrategy {

    protected Wind1Weight1KiteSelectionStrategy() {
        super(5, 10, 40, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public Kite getKite() {
        return new KiteSize10();
    }
}
```

And your kite:

```
public interface Kite {
    String value();
}

public class KiteSize10 implements Kite {
    @Override
    public String value() {
        return "10-11 m^s";
    }
}
```

Disadvantages

- slightly less efficient than nested ifs

Advantages

- WAY more readable
- easily modify and add more use-cases
- less prone to bugs
- maintainable if your table is much larger

Comment: Thanks for your time and code, much appreciated ! @Mor Blau